# How to create a Spark data frame from Pandas data frame using snow flake and python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sql which is stored in a variable in python and we use SnowFlake database. First I have converted to Pandas Data frame using sql, but I need to convert to Spark Data frame and then store in a CreateorReplaceTempView. I tried:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import sf_connectivity (we have a code for establishing connection with Snowflake database)
    emp = 'Select * From Employee'
    snowflake_connection = sf_connectivity.collector() (It is a method to establish snowflake conenction)
    pd_df = pd.read_sql_query(emp, snowflake_connection)
    requirement 1: Create SnowFlake Dataframe (sf_df) from Pandas Dataframe (pd_df)
    requirement 2: sf_df.createOrReplaceTempView(Temp_Employee)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: i dont know snowflake but you can create a spark dataframe by `spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)` , what did you try

Comment: What is the purpose of loading the Snowflake data to a Pandas dataframe first?  Just use the Snowflake Spark connector and create it directly.

Comment: @MikeWalton how to create spark data frame using snowflake connection? Can you please help me out.

Comment: @anky do i need to import any import any packages or libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment in the question above, you'd likely be better off just loading the data directly to a Dataframe in Spark using the Snowflake Spark connector.  Here is a link to the document that details how to do this:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#moving-data-from-snowflake-to-spark